# I cannot get Rabbitmq message to show as unacknowledged

Tags: php, rabbitmq

I have set up Rabbitmq with php, but all messages come in without the unacknowledged flag. Therefore the first receiver to connect gets all messages instantly, so if the receiver goes down, the messages get lost.

This is my sending code:

```
class TaskRunner
{
    public string $queueName = 'tasks3';

    public bool $durable = true;

    public function sendTaskToRabbitmq(string $jobClass, array $arguments)
    {                
        try {
            $connection = new AMQPStreamConnection('rabbitmq', 5672, 'guest', 'guest');
            $channel = $connection->channel();
        } catch(TaskRunnerException $e) {
            error_log("There has been a problem: " . $e->getMessage() . "\n");
            exit;
        }

        $channel->queue_declare($this->queueName, false, $this->durable, false, false);

        $msgString = json_encode([
            'task_class' => $jobClass,
            'arguments' => $arguments
        ]);

        $msg = new AMQPMessage($msgString, array('delivery_mode' => 2));
        $channel->basic_publish($msg, '', $this->queueName);

        echo " [x] Sent ' . $msgString . ' to $this->queueName\n";

        $channel->close();
        $connection->close();
    }
}
```

I have searched for the reason for this, but everything seems to be about acknowledging the requests.  Am I missing something that is causing this issue?

I have tried various configurations and have got the messages to be persistent, so if server goes down, the messages are protected, but they still never come in unacknowledged.

Comment: Can you show the lines from the code where you get the message.

Comment: Please make sure that you didn't set 'no_ack' parameter to true in your consumer code. If it is true, the "auto-acknowledge" mode is used, where rabbit server considers all messages as acknowledged right after the sending them to consumer, without waiting for manual ack. See sources of basic_consume here: https://github.com/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/blob/master/PhpAmqpLib/Channel/AMQPChannel.php#L971

Comment: This is nothing to do with the receiver, It I send the messages without the receiver running, I can see them stack up in the management tool, but they all have the unacked flag blank.  A soon as you start a receiver, it gets all the messages before processing them, so the queue is empty, and if you stop the receiver, the unprocessed messages are lost.  So I need the messages to be added to the queue 'unacknowledged'

Comment: I have tried with auto-ack on and off, and no messaged ever arrive with unacked

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I was misunderstanding how the acks worked.  I needed to submit a lot of requests to the queue to build up enough while being processed and then see the noacks.